# How do I set FastCopy as the default copy handler?

Tags: windows, copy

Teracopy and killcopy, and ultrafastcopy all have a feature to be set as the default copy handler, fastcopy does not. Is there some reg tweak the others are doing to achieve it? I'd like to be able to do the same with fastcopy if possible.